How to automate the PWA app by launching from the desktop
Summary
How can we automate the PWA app by launching from the desktop.
Problem Statement
When we install the app, it gets downloaded to chromeapps and by double click the app opens.
Though I can see the DOM, since it becomes a desktop app how can I launch it through automation script and interact with DOM elements? is there any automation tool/framework that helps doing this. Also PWA apps will have push notifications, how can we validate the same as the notifications will be at the device level. Thanks!
I have tried using selenium and it didn't work
